# Homestead новая база данных

Tags: база-данных, laravel, homestead

У меня развернут homestead для проектов laravel. На виртуальной машине одна база данных ('homestead'). 
Я начинаю второй laravel-проект, который использует одноименные таблицы: migrations, users. Мне стоит создать вторую базу для нового проекта? Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это сделать очень просто

Нужно отредактировать файл `path/to/homestead.yaml`.

Например, у меня настройки сделаны по следующему примеру:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 1500
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\projects\domains\__phpmyadmin
      to: /home/vagrant/www/__phpmyadmin

    - map: C:\projects\domains\example.loc
      to: /home/vagrant/www/example

    - map: C:\projects\domains\example1.loc
      to: /home/vagrant/www/example1

    - map: C:\projects\domains\example2.loc
      to: /home/vagrant/www/example2

sites:
    - map: pma.loc
      to: /home/vagrant/www/__phpmyadmin

    - map: example.loc
      to: /home/vagrant/www/example/public

    - map: example1.loc
      to: /home/vagrant/www/example1/public

    - map: example2.loc
      to: /home/vagrant/www/example2/public

databases:
    - example
    - example1
    - example2
```

и перезапустить vagrant с ключем `--provision` в директории, где находится homestead:

```
vagrant up --provision
```